# Extract .dmg file in C#

Tags: c#, 7zip, dmg

This question recently got into my mind: How can i extract **DMG** file with C#?

---

I did a lot of research and i found that maybe it's possible with 7-zip library to extract it but when i tried, let's say it was disappointing; i can't get it to work!

so i want to ask, is it really possible?

or is there a library for this job?

this is my code:

```
ArchiveFile f = new ArchiveFile("path to dmg file", "path to 7z.dll");

        Console.WriteLine(f.Entries[0].FileName);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What's the error? Who said dmg with 7-zip? Is ArchiveFile part of the 7-zip library, is it a Nuget package?

Comment: @JeremyThompson error was "Unable to initialize SevenZipHandle" and it's sevenzipextractor library

Comment: Can you extract any other format with this method using 7zip?

Comment: @Gui Yes i tried .zip

Comment: "Unable to initialize SevenZipHandle" suggests it can't interact with the 7zip binary. I would expect this to fail with any archive file type. Make sure to compile as 32/64 bit to match your installed 7zip version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'SevenZipExtractor' nuget package, and code similar to yours (below) I faced a couple of issues.

The first issue I faced was a 'SevenZipExtractor.SevenZipException', with an inner exception stating that "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". This was due to compiling as Any CPU, but using a 64 bit 7-zip installation.

The second issue I faced was a Null Reference Exception from within the 'Entries' property of the ArchiveFile class. Decompiling this highlighted that quite a bit was going on in here. I pulled the repository down, removed the nuget package, and referenced the project directly with the intention of debugging the issue in the library, however surprisingly this seemed to work as expected.

[Github: SevenZipExtractor](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor)

Curiously, (or maybe due to my ignorance of the DMG format) my test dmg ([Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)) didn't list the same files I see when I open it with the 7zip File Manager. I was expecting to see a single folder named Firefox, but instead discovered 3 files:

- 0.dmm
- 1.Apple_partition_map
- 2.hfs

I found that the HFS file contained all the files I could see using 7zFM.exe, so I extracted this, and opened it using the same method as previously used on the DMG.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SevenZipExtractor;

namespace _7zip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string workingDirectory = @"C:\Profile\Repositories\7zipPlayground\7zip\bin\Debug\";

            using (var archiveFile = new ArchiveFile(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, "test.dmg"), @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll"))
            {
                var files = archiveFile.Entries?.ToList();

                foreach (var f in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File: {f.FileName}");
                }

                var hfsFile = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileName.ToLower().Contains("hfs"));

                if (hfsFile == null)
                    return;

                hfsFile.Extract(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, hfsFile.FileName));

                using (var hfsArchiveFile = new ArchiveFile(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, hfsFile.FileName), @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll"))
                {
                    files = hfsArchiveFile.Entries?.ToList();

                    foreach (var f in files)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"File: {f.FileName}");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As the above sample is working for me, using my previously installed version of 7zip and the project from the GitHub repository above, I can only assume at this point that there is either something wrong with the way this project is transformed into a nuget package, something wrong with how this package is applied, or a bug has been fixed in the project and the package not yet updated. Regardless, it wasn't entirely clear what your problem was, or where it occurred due to the lack of full code being posted and no stack trace, but I have reproduced a similar issue and progressed past it as described above.